# How to add fade in and fade out when changing between texts in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have below my JAVASCRIPT code which change between 2 words every 2.5 seconds and I want to add fading to the transition between the words in the array it uses. I know that I need to use Jquery but how do I implement it in this recursive function? Any ideas?

```js
var text = ["first", "second"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 2500);

function change() {
  elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-right h2 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin: 15px 0 45px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="changeText">Data Scientist</h2>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using Native JavaScript you could use CSS transitions and `classList`.

Something like:

CSS

```
#changeText {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

JavaScript

```
function change() {
    elem.classList.add('hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
        counter++;
        if (counter >= text.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

#### Demo:

```js
var text = ["first", "second"];
var counter = 0;
var elem = document.getElementById("changeText");
setInterval(change, 2500);

function change() {
    elem.classList.add('hide');
    setTimeout(function () {
        elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
        elem.classList.remove('hide');
        counter++;
        if (counter >= text.length) {
            counter = 0;
        }
    }, 500);
}
```

```css
#changeText {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
.hide {
    opacity: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="changeText">Data Scientist</h2>
```

Note: I used `!important` in the CSS because `opacity: 1;` when applied with a ID selector has priority over a class selector.

Comment: So in jsfiddle it works fine. but when I put all the code in it doesn't have a fading transition. it looks like that it ignores the CSS code.

Comment: @user3882752 can you post the rest of your code or add it to my jsFiddle so I can check it?

Comment: Nevermind. I had another element called "hide" so I just changed yours to "hide2". Thank you very much works great now!

Comment: @user3882752 nice! yeah, I could have used a less common class name also :)

Answer (score 1):

Replace this part:

```
elem.innerHTML = text[counter];
```

With:

```
$(elem)
    .fadeOut(400)
    .html(text[counter])
    .delay(400)
    .fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: This works. But, as you can see I have some text in html ("Data Scientist") as well and the text there does not have the fading effect. Plus, because I have another element in the div (banner-right) once it fades out the other element changes its location because the text faded out. How do I solve these two problems? Take a look http://jsfiddle.net/yjodpLus/