# Set transition between innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Need to add fade in and out transition on innerHTML.

I have looked around but didn't find a solution to accomplish this.

I wish to have fade in and out effect between innerHTML texts.

```js
var h2text = ["First h2", "Second H2"];
var counter = 0;
var h2 = document.getElementById("changeH2");
var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);
function change() {
  h2.innerHTML = h2text[counter];
  counter++;
  if (counter >= h2text.length) {
    counter = 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 id="changeH2"></h2>
```

Comment: Can you provide some *relevant* javascript?   Can't see how a counter is relevant.  **Edit** running the snippet makes it clearer - you want to toggle between two values with a fadein/out between them

Comment: Yes it should work now, forgot to add the HTML.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add fade in and fade out when changing between texts in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31313589/how-to-add-fade-in-and-fade-out-when-changing-between-texts-in-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise CSS classes and [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) to do this by fading the element in and out when the text changes. I've also included another timeout.

```js
var h2text = ["First h2", "Second H2"];
var counter = 0;
var h2 = document.getElementById("changeH2");
var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);
function change() {
  h2.classList.add('fade');
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    h2.innerHTML = h2text[counter];
      h2.classList.remove('fade');
   counter++;
      if (counter >= h2text.length) {
        counter = 0;
    }  
  }, 500);
}
```

```css
h2{
  transition: opacity .5s ease;
}

.fade{
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 id="changeH2"></h2>
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. However, the first text shows twice when I apply this to my page, any idea what could cause this?

Comment: @Tane Do you have the first text in the H2 by default, i.e `<h2>You have text here</h2>`? If so, start the counter at one, or swap the items in the array. Without seeing your code, I can't say for 100% sure.

Answer (score 1):

Improved a little your js (using modulo instead of your three-line-condition), and created a small animation that seems to fit your requirements.

```js
let h2text = ["First h2", "Second H2"];
let counter = 0;
let h2 = document.getElementById("changeH2");
let inst = setInterval(change, 2000);

function change() {
  h2.innerHTML = h2text[counter];
  counter = (counter + 1) % h2text.length;
}
```

```css
#changeH2{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: fade infinite 2s;
}

@keyframes fade{
  20%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
  80%{
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<h2 id="changeH2"></h2>
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you, it works. However, for some reason, on my page the first text is shown twice, and then it starts working normally, any idea what could cause this?

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve this bij using the opacity like this

```js
var h2text = ["First h2", "Second H2"];
var h2 = document.getElementById("changeH2");
h2.style.transition = "0.5s"; //fade speed

setTimeout(function () {
  h2.style.opacity = 0; //make text temporarily invisible
  setTimeout(function() {
    h2.innerHTML = h2text[1];
    h2.style.opacity = 1; //fade back in
  }, 500); //this timeout needs to be the same as the transition speed   
})
```

```html
<h2 id="changeH2">First h2<h2/>
```

Here you don't have to do anything with your css.

Answer (score 0):

Simple plugin for text transition.

```js
(function($) {
  let KeyWord = ["First h2", "Second H2"];
  let counter = 0;
  let Flag = true;

  function rotaterator() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (counter == 2) {
        counter = 0;
      }
      if (Flag) {
        Flag = false;
        counter = 1;
      }

      $("#changeH2").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#changeH2").text(KeyWord[counter]);
        counter++;
      }).fadeIn(function() {});
      rotaterator();
    }, 2000);
  }
  rotaterator();
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="changeH2"></h2>
```